# How to determine if device location permission is denied twice in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location, core-location

If Location Service is disabled in iPhone(Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services) and when requested for location permission using `self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` then app shows system dialog with settings and cancel button.

[image]

On click of settings button it redirects Device's location service page.

[image]

If Cancel is tapped alert dismisses. And if second time I ask for permission and tap cancel, alert dismisses. And then again if I request third time for location permission then that above system dialog won't be shown.

I have tried `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` which gives me Device location is enabled or disabled. In case of disable state I have written `self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` which shows system dialog twice only. Now how shall I determine that system dialog has been denied twice? So that I can show my custom dialog.

Comment: Not sure how you are able to tap the cancel button twice. I would imagine after pressing it once the alert would be dismissed. Basic concept is once the user has decided not to give access to location the OS wouldn't keep asking the user again and whenever the developer decided to ask. Ask only when needed use and exactly before the time of usage.

Comment: @user1046037 I updated the que, am requesting again once alert is dismissed after tapping cancel. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to repeatedly keep asking till the user gives permission?

Comment: @user1046037 Not exactly, But when user comes back again and wants to access location feature then I have asked for permission.

Comment: Could you post minimum reproducible code so that we could have a look?

Answer (score 2):

if I understand well (your question is a little bit confused) you can do it with UserDefaults like that, I use alert but you can use your code in if statement:

import CoreLocation, set func and UserDefaults:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class Prova: UIViewController {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager() // location manager

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager)
}

var control = 0 // set var to control user tap denied
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    switch manager.authorizationStatus {
    case .authorizedAlways , .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("authorized always and when in use")
        break
    case .notDetermined , .denied , .restricted:
        
        print("authorized denied or restricted")
        let res = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "ok")
        control = res
        UserDefaults.standard.set(res, forKey: "ok")
        
        if res >= 1 { // first = 0 second = 1 - Two times
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Ooooooop!", message: "you're denied or restricted for two times", preferredStyle: .alert)
                myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive))
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.control + 1, forKey: "ok")
                self.present(myAlert, animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "OK", message: "you're denied for: \(self.control + 1) times", preferredStyle: .alert)
                myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive))
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.control + 1, forKey: "ok")
                self.present(myAlert, animated: true)
            }
        }
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    print(" time denied:",control)
 }
}
```